# Rendering and process same form twice in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a requirement of rendering and processing the same form again if user check a select box. I looked into form collections but it didn't exactly access my problem because I don't need to render a set of fields instead my requirement is to render the complete form again. So what I added another function getClone($prefix) to get the clone of form which returns me the clone of form object after adding a prefix in the name of form. Like this

```
<?php

namespace Company\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class CompanyAddress extends Form implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($countries, $name = 'null') {
        parent::__construct('company_address');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('id', 'company_address');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'street_1',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'street_1',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Street *',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'street_2',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'street_2',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Street 2',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'country_id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'country_id',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Country',
                'value_options' => $countries
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'city_id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'city_id',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'City ',
                'value_options' => array()
            )
        ));



        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'zip',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'zip',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'ZIP',
                'value_options' => array()
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'address_type',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'zip',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Type',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '' => 'Select Type',
                    'default' => 'Default',
                    'invoice' => 'Invoice',
                    'both' => 'Both',
                )
            )
        ));

    }

    public function getClone($prefix){
        $form = clone $this;
        foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
            $name = $element->getName();
            $element->setName("$prefix[$name]");
        }
        return $form;
    }

    public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'street_1',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array('message' => 'Street cannot be empty'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'street_2',
                        'required' => false,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                        ),
                    )));

             $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'city_id',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array('message' => 'City cannot be empty'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));

             $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'country_id',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array('message' => 'Country cannot be empty'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));

             $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'zip',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array('message' => 'ZIP cannot be empty'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));

             $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'address_type',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array('message' => 'Address Type cannot be empty'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));


            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

}
```

and than in my action I did this

```
public function testAction() {
    $countries = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Country')->getSelect();
    $companyAddressForm = new CompanyAddressForm($countries);
    $clone = $companyAddressForm->getClone('address2');
    if($this->request->isPost()){
        $data = $this->request->getPost();
        $companyAddressForm->setData($data);
        $clone->setData($data['address2']);
        $isFormOneValid = $companyAddressForm->isValid();
        //$isFormTwoValid = $clone->isValid();
    }
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->companyAddressForm = $companyAddressForm;
    $view->clone = $clone;
    return $view;

}
```

This is working as I expected it to work, forms are rendering and validating correctly, I want to know whether it is a correct way or a hack?

Comment: Can you use isValid() with different params? `isValid($params1)` and `isValid($params2)`. Without `setData`.

Comment: no to validate a form you need to setData first, isValid will not work untill you set data

Comment: right, my answer is for zf1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the forms are exactly the same then you don't need to declare and validate two forms in the controller action.

Reason:

If there are two forms rendered your HTML page. Only one of the forms can be posted by the users at a time and you need to validate only one form at a time. What you are doing now is to validate the same form with the same post data over again. So either $isFormOneValid, $isFormTwoValid are both true or both false.

Instead, declare only one form, render it twice in your view, and upon post, validate it with the post data. If the two forms differ in properties, filters, validators, etc. then you can create two methods like $form->applyForm1Validarots() and $form->applyForm2Validarots, check the value of your select element, and call the appropriate method to apply the validaorts / filters before calling isValid() on it.

Hope I helped

Comment: I think I was unable to explain my point, in one scenario I do need to process the same form with different data and hence I need to validate data of coming from the both duplicate forms